# REACT.jsx not showing in Browser

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm currently in the process of learning React. However, I'm having a ton of trouble trying to get this to run.

**HTML**

```js
function Person(){
    return (
        <div class="person">
        <h1>Max</h1>
        <p>Your Age: 28</p>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Person />, document.querySelector('#p1'));
```

```css
.person {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #ccc;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="react.css">

</head>
<body>
    
    <!-- He created a div block with a class of person -->    <link rel="stylesheet" href="react.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="p1">

    </div>

    <!-- He makes another div -->
    <div class="person">
            <h1>Manu</h1>
            <p>Your Age: 29</p>
        </div>
        
        <script src="react.jsx"></script>
```

Sorry for the comments.
I feel like most of my problem really boils down to the script source. Whenever I try to load this on CodePen (Using Babel) it works perfectly. I'm not sure how to get this to run. If I run this in my browser I will see...

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I tried to use the CDN for Babel JS from[this site](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/babel-core) but if I add this and change the above script to "type="text/bable" it won't even show up.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(<Person />, document.querySelector('#p1'));` should be `ReactDOM.render('<Person />', document.querySelector('#p1'));`

Comment: is there more to the document or did you just copy paste certain section of your code?  Can you load your entire code to codepen or codesandbox.io and share it with us

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have 2 body tags; one of them is in head. Not sure if that's what's giving you the error, but I just happened to notice that. Seems like the error message has to do with a stray '<' somewhere.

Comment: For some bizarre reason, when I posted this HTML snippet it included 2 body tags. Those aren't in my current HTML though!

Answer (score 0):

JSX is not standard JavaScript.  You have to transpile that with some sort of build step (like Babel) or load in the in the transpiling script so you can use JSX in the browser.  This was available a couple years ago, but I can't seem to find it anymore.

Comment: Here is the JSX transformer link, but it doesn't seem that React supports this method at all anymore.  Might still work though.
https://shripadk.github.io/react/downloads.html#jsx-transformer.

Answer (score 0):

JSX is not supported by browser directly.
To play React with JSX you need to use Babel (online converter).
Add following `<script>` to main html file.

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>`

And add `type="text/babel"` attribute to `script` tag where use add JSX file. In your case it will be `<script type="text/babel" src="react.jsx"></script>`

Source: [Try React with JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#optional-try-react-with-jsx)